# How to share one Apscheduler Jobstore over 2 Django instances

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I am running a Django App that creates 2 instances. 
I am using BackgroundScheduler to schedule a job and later remove it based on some conditions.
Since there are 2 Django instances, the job still gets executed by the other instance.
Is there a way to share a Jobstore over different instances so that I can still run 2 instances?

Comment: Have you read the FAQ? Especially this section? https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes